# Merging a long dataset with a wide dataset

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I currently have two datasets. The first is in long format:

```
animal      name
dog         jim
dog         jake
dog         ian
cat         luke
cat         james
```

etc.

The second is a wide dataset like so:

```
dog      cat
adam     dennis
boris    NA
clive    NA
```

I want to move all my data from the first dataset into the second dataset under the appropriate columns, so ideally I will end up with:

```
 dog      cat
adam     dennis
boris    luke
clive    james
jim      NA
jake     NA
Ian      NA
```

However, I am struggling with how to do this. I've tried melting the wide dataset but when recasting it it doesn't return the right result.

Cheers for the help

Comment: Obvious answer here is to convert to long and merge. However, you have duplicated entries which will make things very difficult when merging

Comment: How do you know boris should be matched with luke and not james?

Comment: Sorry, the expectant results are in wide format. So all dog names are one column, cat another. Whereas I have the raw results in long format (first table).

Comment: How are the 2 tables related to each other? If you're trying to join them, what are you joining by? Or are you basically just binding them?

Comment: You can have a look at my answer to see if that is the desired output

Comment: They are related by the type of animal the name is related to. I should have picked a less stupid analogy than animal names....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `base R`. Maybe this is what you want

```
df2 <- rbind(df2,sapply(names(df2),function(v) ifelse(df1$animal==v,
                                                      df1$name[df1$animal==v],
                                                      NA)))
dfout <- data.frame(lapply(r <- Map(na.omit,df2), `length<-`,max(lengths(r))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
    dog    cat
1  adam dennis
2 boris  james
3 clive   luke
4   jim   <NA>
5  jake   <NA>
6   ian   <NA>
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- structure(list(animal = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"), 
    name = c("jim", "jake", "ian", "luke", "james")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(dog = c("adam", "boris", "clive", "jim", "jake", 
"ian", NA, NA), cat = c("dennis", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "james", 
"luke")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is so close! Except it seems not all values from df1 are incorporated into df2, though those that are are merged into the right column!

Comment: @Elsybelsy, All names in `df1` has been merged into `df2`, nothing is missing...it looks the same as your desired output in your post